# VBA printout code skips prints of paper when I loop thrue list

Tags: excel, vba, time, printing, while-loop

I am doing a while loop that prints out a picking sheet. But I am having trouble when I go through the stacks of papers, that some sheets are missing. For about 40 sheets of paper, 2 sheets will be missing.

I have tried to add a wait timer so it will wait 4 seconds between every print. This actually fixed the problem, but it takes me 35 min to print through the loop. I even tried to turn down the timer to 2-3 seconds but the results were negative.

```
With Sheets("Utskrift").Range("D3")
' '   If .Value = "" Then
       .Value = Sheets("Butiker").Range("D3").Value
       If Sheets("Utskrift").Range("L2") >= 1 And Sheets("Utskrift").Range("L2") <= 68 Or Sheets("Utskrift").Range("L3") >= 1 And Sheets("Utskrift").Range("L3") <= 16 Then
               ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1
               Application.Wait Now + #12:00:04 AM#

            ElseIf Sheets("Utskrift").Range("L2") > 68 Then
               ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=2
               Application.Wait Now + #12:00:04 AM#

            Else:


            End If

  Do While Sheets("Utskrift").Range("D3") > ""
        v = Application.Match(.Value, Sheets("Butiker").Range("D3:D9"), 0)
        If IsNumeric(v) Then
            .Value = Sheets("Butiker").Range("D3:D9").Cells(v + 1, 1).Value
            If Sheets("Utskrift").Range("L2") >= 1 And Sheets("Utskrift").Range("L2") <= 68 Or Sheets("Utskrift").Range("L3") >= 1 And Sheets("Utskrift").Range("L3") <= 16 Then
               ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1
               Application.Wait Now + #12:00:04 AM#

            ElseIf Sheets("Utskrift").Range("L2") > 68 Then
               ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=2
               Application.Wait Now + #12:00:04 AM#

            Else:


            End If
        Else
            .Value = ""
        End If
    Loop
End With
```

Is there any other way I can do this to ensure that every sheet of paper get's printed and I do not have to wait 4 seconds? Or maybe there is a way to check which papers did not get printed, and then I could just reprint those afterwards.

Comment: What does `.Value` reference (please edit your question and add the `With` line to your code)?  Offtopic: Haven't seen a comparison `Range("D3") > ""` before, should be `Do While Sheets("Utskrift").Range("D3") <> ""`.

Comment: Hi Asger!  The .Value references to a list of store names that varies from day to day.  D3 is a scroll down list that cycles thrue the store list (.value).  The list can vary in length, so if comes to an end and finds a blank space, " " , it should end.